# How to stream videos RESTfully using AngularJS?

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, video, stream

I'm building a site with a Java back end and an AngularJS front end. The front and back end communicate RESTfully. I'm able to send images RESTfully to the front end from the back end by sending a bit stream but I'm a bit confused on how to do this with videos.

Are there any frameworks or guides that allow integration of RESTful video streaming? I'm sort of lost on how to do this as it's a lot more difficult than sending images.